# Application permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have enabled a user of my application to enable permissions to view photo albums.

However, what I really want is to not only enable the application to access the photo albums but to enable the user to select one image from the album that other users of the application can then see thereafter.

This is a competition application so the user selects an image and that image is included in the competition but users of the application must be able to view so as they can vote on it.

Must I take the image from the photo album and upload to a hosting server or is there away I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is an application in your server which saves the photo the user has selected. Then you save the reference of this photo into a database and when other users comes to your application you request all of these in the database and show them back to the user.

This is a pretty basic programming structure, so Facebook serves you with a lot of shared data through many profiles. On the other hand, you are in charge of what you do with these data, how you use it and in which applications you implement it. Remember when you do this, you have to provide a privacy policy and a terms of use document to avoid any legal consequence to your end.

Comment: Cheers Joe. How you have detailed is how i have done before. I just thought i would check this. I have actually just realized an alternative way to deal with this. When the permissions are granted, i have access to all the absolute urls for the images. I can store these urls in the db rather than uploading the image selected. Through testing, it seems that this absolute url doesn't require permissions to reference.

Comment: PS "When the permissions are granted, i have access to all the absolute urls for the images" Trhough the graph api

Comment: well remember the user might delete this pictures and would not be available for later use. That's why I do recommend the sync process this way you are consistent with your data.