# API permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388345/application-permissions)

If I grant permission to an application to, say, access my photos,

Does the application thereafter have the ability to access those photos when another user is using the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that when you have the permissions from a user and another user enters and you want to serve this user the information of another user that is not it friend, I think you cannot.

The application has permissions of accessing this data through an access token that is generated when the users log into the application. This means:

1. User enters the application and accept permissions the first time.
2. The application receives a user object with an access token
   related to this.
3. The application uses the given access token to retrieve data from
   the current logged-in user.
4. The application can access this data as long as the user is logged-in and
   has a valid access token.
5. When the user leaves the application and closes the session, the application
   will no longer has a valid access token to retrieve this user data.

So from what I have read in the Facebook documentation, you cannot access an user's photos from your application unless this user is the one logged-in and with a valid access token.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Thats exactly how i thought things were happening.

Comment: There are some works around if what you want to do is a photo public pool in which you need to save the retrieved data in your server and then give access to it to any logged user, you might need to ask the first time for an user to synchronize a desired album with the service but remember to provide a valid Privacy Policy and a clear Terms of Use to avoid any legal action an user might take towards your application manager or developers.

Answer (score 0):

No - the access token you get back is specific to that user and will only ever allow you to access that users information (and possibly their friends permissions if you asked for friends permission).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Once you grant permission, application will be able to access the data you allowed it to access at any time.

Comment: Darvex! Even if i am a different user? That doesnt sound right? I thought Joes account of steps seemed more likely